# Derivative of complex quadratic form-functions with respect to a vector

Tags: vectors, tensor-products, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product, symbolic-computation

I have a quadratic form like this:

$Q_1=v_1^TC_1(x)v_1$

$Q_2=v_2^TC_2(y)v_2$

where

$x,y,z$ - $3 \times 1$-vectors

$J_1,J_2,C_1,C_2$ - $3 \times 3$-matrix

$v_1=x-(J_1(x)y-z),v_2=x-(J_2(y)y-z)$

Derivatives-by-vector will be determined by the chain rule:

$\frac{dQ_1}{dx}=\frac{dv_1}{dx}^TC_1v_1+v_1^T\frac{dC_1}{dx}v_1+v_1^TC_1\frac{dv_1}{dx}$

$\frac{dQ_2}{dy}=\frac{dv_2}{dy}^TC_2v_2+v_2^T\frac{dC_2}{dy}v_2+v_2^TC_2\frac{dv_2}{dy}$

It's obvious that:

$\frac{dv_1}{dx}=\frac{dv_1}{dx}^T$ and $\frac{dv_2}{dy}=\frac{dv_2}{dy}^T$

If I'm not mistaken, then the derivative $v_1,v_2,v_3$ by vectors:

$\frac{dv_1}{dx}=I-(\frac{dJ_1}{dx}(y \otimes I))$

$\frac{dv_2}{dy}=-(\frac{dJ_2}{dy}(y \otimes I)+J_2)$

But the problem is that complex vector-matrix symbolic calculations are difficult to do, and the capabilities of software packages are limited. Let's assume that for the most part I work with expressions of the types in question. What will the derivatives of quadratic form-functions with respect to vectors look like in a simpler form?

Comment: I have yet for find a CAS package that handles vectors well. What I end up doing often is writing down the expressions in `LyX` for typesetting, and doing the simplifications, trig. identities or what is needed by hand. The problem with CAS is that it will always produce results in terms of the vector components and you loose the insight you might have otherwise. For example try to expand out $a \cdot ( b \times c)$ into components.

Comment: Are $C_1$ and $C_2$ symmetric?

Comment: @JAlex this matrices has arbitrary structure

Comment: This notation is tricky as $\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}x}J_{1}(x)$ is not a matrix, but a rank 3 tensor.

Comment: @JAlex Yes, I also tried to simplify the notation, trying to find a matrix structure that would allow this. But so far without success.

Comment: The closest you can get is from the derivative of an orthonormal matrix $R$ which is $$ \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} R = [\tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec{\theta} \times] R$$ with the part inside the brackets being a 3×3 skew symmetric matrix. But that is a derivative against a common independent variable, and not a spatial direction.

Comment: @JAlex I think, that this option may be useful in some cases. I'll try to find something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Start with the $v_\o$ variable, but for ease of typing we'll drop all subscripts.
$$\eqalign{
v &= x+z - Jy \\
dv &= dx - J\,dy - dJ\,y \\
 &= dx - J\,dy - \LR{y^T\otimes I}\vecc{dJ} \\
\grad{v}{x}
 &= \grad{x}{x} - J\,{\gradLR yx} - \LR{y^T\otimes I}\gradLR{\vecc{J}}{x} \\
 &= I - \LR{y^T\otimes I}\gradLR{j}{x} \\
}$$
Then move on to the first quadratic form
$$\eqalign{
Q &= vv^T:C  \\
 &= \vecc{vv^T}:\vecc C \\
 &= \LR{v\otimes v}:c \\
dQ &= \LR{v\otimes v}:dc \;+\; C:\LR{dv\,v^T+v\,dv^T} \\
 &= \LR{v\otimes v}:dc \;+\; \LR{C+C^T}v:dv \\
 &= \LR{v\otimes v}:\gradLR{c}{x}dx \;+\; \LR{C+C^T}v:\gradLR{v}{x}dx \\
 &= \gradLR{c}{x}^T\LR{v\otimes v}:dx \;+\; \gradLR{v}{x}^T\LR{C+C^T}v:dx \\
\grad{Q}{x}
 &= \gradLR{c}{x}^T\LR{v\otimes v} \;+\; \gradLR{v}{x}^T\LR{C+C^T}v \\
 &= \gradLR{c}{x}^T\LR{v\otimes v}
 \;+\; \LR{I - \LR{y^T\otimes I}\gradLR{j}{x}}^T\LR{C+C^T}v \\
 &= \gradLR{c}{x}^T\LR{v\otimes v} \;+\; \LR{C+C^T}v
 \;-\; \gradLR{j}{x}^T{\LR{y\otimes I}}\LR{C+C^T}v \\
\\
}$$
In this derivation, we [vectorized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) some of the matrix variables. This allowed us to avoid matrix-by-vector gradients (which are tensor-valued) and  write the result using standard vector-by-vector gradients (which are matrix-valued).

We also introduced the symbols  $(\otimes)$ to denote the Kronecker product and $(:)$ to denote the Frobenius product $-$ which is really just a concise notation for the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
A:A &= \|A\|^2_F \\
}$$
When applied to vector variables, the Frobenius product reduces to the standard dot product.

The properties of the underlying trace function allow the terms in a
Frobenius product to be rearranged in many different ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:B &= A^T:B^T \\
C:\LR{AB} &= \LR{CB^T}:A \\&= \LR{A^TC}:B \\
}$$

Comment: Hm, I learned a few new tools. I still need to deal with them more closely, but your suggestion is a good starting point for further work. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some steps to consider, with 3×3 matrices.

A general matrix C can be decomposed into three matrices, each derived from a single vector.

$$ C = \mathrm{diag}(\vec{d}) + \vec{c} \odot \vec{c} + [ \vec{w} \times] $$

where $\odot$ is the outer product, ${\rm diag}()$ creates a matrtix from the vector in its diagonal elements and $[\vec{w}\times]$ is the skew-symmetric cross product operator matrix

$$ {\rm diag}(\vec{d}) = \begin{bmatrix} d_1 & & \\ & d_2 & \\ & & d_3 \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ \vec{c} \odot \vec{c} = \begin{bmatrix} c_1^2 & c_1 c_2 & c_1 c_3 \\ c_1 c_2 & c_2^2 & c_2 c_3 \\ c_1 c_3 & c_2 c_3 & c_3^2 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ [\vec{w}\times] = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -w_3 & w_2 \\ w_3 & 0 & -w_1 \\ -w_2 & w_1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

The definition of each vector is

$$ \vec{w} = \pmatrix{ 
 \frac{C_{3,2}-C_{2,3}}{2} \\
 \frac{C_{1,3}-C_{3,1}}{2} \\
 \frac{C_{2,1}-C_{1,2}}{2} }  \\
$$

$$ \vec{d} = \pmatrix{
  C_{1,1} - \frac{ (C_{2,1}+C_{1,2}) (C_{3,1}+C_{1,3})}{2 \sqrt{C_{3,2}+C_{2,3}} } \\
  C_{2,2} - \frac{ (C_{2,1}+C_{1,2}) (C_{3,2}+C_{2,3})}{2 \sqrt{C_{3,1}+C_{1,3}} } \\
  C_{3,3} - \frac{ (C_{3,1}+C_{1,3}) (C_{3,2}+C_{2,3})}{2 \sqrt{C_{3,1}+C_{1,2}} }
} $$

and

$$\vec{c} = \pmatrix{
 \sqrt{ \frac{ (C_{2,1}+C_{1,2}) (C_{3,1}+C_{1,3})}{2 (C_{3,2}+C_{2,3}) } }\\
 \sqrt{ \frac{ (C_{2,1}+C_{1,2}) (C_{3,2}+C_{2,3})}{2 (C_{3,1}+C_{1,3}) }  }\\
 \sqrt{ \frac{ (C_{3,1}+C_{1,3}) (C_{3,2}+C_{2,3})}{2 (C_{2,1}+C_{1,2}) } }
} $$

So now the derivative of $C$ can be evaluated with linear algebra in terms of the derivatives of each vector

$$\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}C=\mathrm{diag}(\left(\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\vec{d}\right))+2\left(\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\vec{c}\right)\odot\vec{c}+[\left(\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\vec{w}\right)\times]$$

and each part maintains its structure in general, which means it can be used for further simplifications. The exception is $\vec{c} \odot \vec{c}$ is symmetric, whereas $ \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \vec{c} \odot \vec{c}$ isn't.

Comment: The derivative of the outer product might be $\left(\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\vec{c}\right)\odot\vec{c}+\vec{c}\odot\left(\tfrac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\vec{c}\right)$ since $\odot$ isn't associative.

Comment: Alternate definition of $\vec{d}$ is $$ d_i = C_{i,i} - c_i^2$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was unable to simplify the derivative of a quadratic form-functions $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ with respect to a vector $x,y$ using your method. The expression is lengthened due to the breakdown into additional terms, acquiring a less compact form. I haven't been able to roll it up yet. I'll work on this some more.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that the formula should include, in addition to the tensor product, and as a result resemble the derivative of a quadratic form with respect to the vector, i.e. $\frac{d}{dx}x^TAx=(A+A^T)x$. This is just a hypothesis, it needs to be tested.